# La etiqueta html no me toma el 100% en algunas resoluciones

Tags: html, css, html5, web, diseño

estoy maquetando una web y me encontre con un problema que no puedo descifrar. Estoy arreglando los media querys de las distintas resoluciones pero me encuentro con que en 2 resoluciones el html dice que esta al 100% pero se reduce a un porcentaje del ancho achicando todo el contenido. Les dejo una captura para que vean el problema.
En una resolución entre 768 y 1024 el html no cubre el 100% aunque está indicado en la etiqueta

En una resolución entre 425 y 768 el html cubre el 100%

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En una resolución entre 768 y 1024 el html cubre no cubre el 100% aunque este indicado en la etiqueta. Todo el contenido en el interior se va achicando a medida que se va reduciendo la resolución hasta que llega al otro punto de quiebre donde todo se reacomoda al 100%.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La página de la que estoy editando está online acá http://www.heist.com.ar/bw3.html

Les agradesco de antemano la ayuda. Seguramente hay muchos errores aún en el maquetado, si ven alguno espantoso será bienvenido el aviso.

Comment: Hola Pluma, deberías añadir el código a la pregunta en sí y no sólo capturas de pantalla. Las preguntas pidiendo ayuda con problemas de depuración deben incluir una descripción del problema (lo tienes), el resultado esperado (lo tienes) y el código mínimo para reproducir el problema en la propia pregunta (se puede ver en la página enlazada, pero una vez lo corrijas, ya no se verá y tu pregunta dejará de tener sentido). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Ah bueno, perdón, no lo sabía. De todas formas en este caso opte por poner la web online y las imágenes porque la verdad no sabía que pedazo de código del html o del css era el que me estaba generando el error. Mil disculpas. Si queres ahora que se donde estaba el problema pongo la parte del código que lo estaba generando.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un error común: la etiqueta html sí ocupa el 100% del ancho, el problema es que hay un elemento que ocupa más del 100% y eso hace que se salga y dé la impresión de que el html no ocupa el 100%.

En concreto tienes puesto que algunas secciones deben tener un ancho de 980px cuando el ancho de pantalla es más de 768px. Eso hace que aunque la página (y la etiqueta html van a tener un ancho menor que 980px, tus secciones y slideshow van a tener un ancho de 980px).

Si cambias los estilos que tienes para `.contenedor-secciones` para que en lugar de tener un ancho de 980px tengan un ancho del 100% con un ancho máximo de 980px, el problema se solucionará (tienes que aplicar unos estilos similares para `.cycle-slideshow`).

Comment: wow, eso sí que fue rápido. Gracias Alvaro, el problema estaba exactamente ahí. Corregí los width y agregue max-width en los contenedores de cada sección y todo arreglado. Mil gracias, estoy hace 5 horas con esto y creo que solo no lo habría sacado nunca. Abrazo.